# Faild to load resource jquery ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript application that was working fine, then seemingly for no reason it broke and is giving me this error message:

```
Failed to load `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`
```

I'm not even sure what relevant code I can post since I have no idea what the error means and nothing I wrote seems to have caused the problem.

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Nothing you can do about this part. Try using a different CDN. It works for me here, though. Try clearing your cache and check?

Comment: There's a redirect loop at that CDN. It's redirecting to itself, or to something else that redirects back.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me what CDN to try and how to change it?

Comment: @RichardGarfield Try CloudFlare: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use that link

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js
```

this is another CDN link and always work for me

Comment: Should have been a comment mate.

Comment: Thank you vey much, this problem only happened on some computers.

Comment: @AleDC only happen on some distribution areas.

Comment: Using Google CDN also works: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Most often I see people using Google's. In case you're interested

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

They also host [many other libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)